# ReactJS using .sort() method mixing up results in array

Tags: javascript, sorting, reactjs

I have an array of data that queries the results through a prop. I am able to obtain the data but, unable to sort it. I want all the data with `MyTeam` to appear first.

However, when I load this into the browser I obtain different results.

In Safari the data lists `MyTeam` to be the second element in the array

In Chrome, the data lists `MyTeam` to be the third element but, whenever I interact with them (via an `onClick` method) the data swaps around in a different order.

If I don't have the .sort() method, everything remains the same and nothing changes.

Is there a proper way to sort the array?

```
    var gameList = this.props.data.sort(function(game) {
        return (game.homeTeam == 'MyTeam' || game.awayTeam == 'MyTeam') ? 0 : 1;
    }).map(function(game, i) {
       //console.log(game.homeTeam + ' ' + game.awayTeam);
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#sort` compares TWO items of the array. Your compare function must have two arguments. I suggest the following:

```
var gameList = this.props.data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var matchA = a.homeTeam === 'MyTeam' || a.awayTeam === 'MyTeam';
    var matchB = b.homeTeam === 'MyTeam' || b.awayTeam === 'MyTeam';

    // This will return
    // -1 if matchA is true and matchB is false
    //  0 if matchA and matchB are both true or both false
    //  1 if matchA is false and matchB is true
    return (matchB ? 1 : 0) - (matchA ? 1 : 0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this seems to place `MyTeam` first now and is stable in Safari. The results still seem a bit wonky though in Chrome and keep jumping around (with `MyTeam` staying as the first result)

Comment: Well sort isn't guaranteed to be stable. The order of a and b is arbitrary if the compare function returns 0.

Comment: Thanks @David Is there no stable method at the moment to sort through the arrays?

Comment: If you want a particular order, you'll need to choose something else to sort on. Suppose each has a unique numeric id. You could change it to: `return (matchB ? 1 : 0) - (matchA ? 1 : 0) || b.id - a.id;`